# Nuxt: Use multiple params for dynamic routing

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have set up a working dynamic route with 'id' as the dynamic parameter:

```
<nuxt-link :to="{ name: `blog-id`, params: { id: item.id }}">Link</nuxt-link>
```

But I'd prefer to use my pages slug as the parameter AND still somehow pass the id. Like only using `./blog/very-awesome-slug`.
I know how to simply use the slug instead of the id but, since there will be an API call to `http://my-backend/api/pages/${this.$route.params.id}`, the id is also needed.

So how would I set up dynamic routing where the slug is used for the route itself but an id is also passed along to call the API?

Comment: blog-id will be `./pages/blog/_id.vue` which would be `/blog/123`, if you want `/blog/1234/foo-bar` then you use `./pages/blog/_id/_slug.vue`, then both id and slug will be in .params

Comment: And if you want to have `/pages/blog-12/`, it is available in nuxt3 with the `/pages/blog-[id]` syntax. More info can be found here: http://v3.nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/pages/#dynamic-routes

Comment: Well, I figured that but I'd prefer a route without id at all `./pages/blog/awesome-slug` but still passing on the id. But maybe it is not possible?

Comment: you can pass arbitrary values in the nuxt-link, so `./blog/very-awesome-slug` receives the numeric id but that's obviously not going to work for direct  links to `./blog/very-awesome-slug`, *think page refresh or search engine crawler* really if you use just the slug then query the API by slug not numeric id, if slugs are not unique, then you need to use both the id and the slug, the solution is more of a design one rather then a nuxt one

Comment: @LawrenceCherone You gave the right nudge! My slugs are unique but I overlooked the fact that I can also query the API via slug! I am still new to decoupled systems. If you turn your comment to an answer I happily accept.